# How Can I convert Image of Base64 String into blob using react js?

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I am using react-webcam for capturing picture. I got the captured image in Base 64. I want to convert it into Blob

```
  capture = () => {

    const imageSrc = this.webcam.getScreenshot();
    Blob imageFile = someFunction(imageSrc) // want this code
    this.setState({
      imgsource: imageFile 
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about this. You can look at the following solutions:

- [Creating a Blob from Base64 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
- [Convert Base64 to a Blob](https://gist.github.com/fupslot/5015897)